# several thread = several Application Context?

Tags: android, multithreading, applicationcontext

it's been giving me headaches for the past 3 days :
I have a MyApp extending Application.
When I call getApplication() from my services (running in different threads), I get a different instance of MyApp than when I call getApplication() from activites running in the main thread.
Is that a normal behavior ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless your services are running in different *processes* this shouldn't happen. Are you sure they are actually different instances? On what platform are you testing?

Comment: you were right, it's actually different processes :
    <service android:name=".service.MusicPlayerService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:process=":sys0">
I may be a bit confused about differences between threads and processes, and I can't remember why I've made that choice..

Comment: In that case, this the expected behaviour.